# NullPointerException when trying to use MutableLiveData value

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

This is my ViewModel

```
 class ManualInputViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var username: MutableLiveData<String>? = null
    var password: MutableLiveData<String>? = null

    fun onClickLogin(view: View){
        view.context.toast(username?.value!!)
    }
 }
```

This is my activity

```
class ManualInputActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    var binding : ActivityManualInputBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_manual_input)
    var viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ManualInputViewModel::class.java)
    binding.viewmodel = viewModel
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this
}
}
```

this is my xml code for the edit text

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
        android:text="@={viewmodel.username}"/>
```

I want just toast the username but I am getting the error

kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at com.aseemsalim.databindingpractice.ui.rubikscube.colorinput.ManualInputViewModel.onClickLogin(ManualInputViewModel.kt:15)

Comment: Could you please add XML code as well.

Comment: Why would your ViewModel be responsible for showing a toast? Wouldn't that be a more natural fit for your Activity or Fragment?

Comment: @Michael just I want to know its working or not

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi I have added the 'EditText' code

Comment: "onClickLogin" This method is getting called from where?

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi from a button `android:onClick="@{viewmodel::onClickLogin}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must init LiveData properties:

```
class ManualInputViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var username = MutableLiveData<String>()
    var password = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun onClickLogin(view: View){
        view.context.toast(username.value)
    }
 }
```

Comment: how can I add getter and setter, can you explain

Comment: And this will won't work if there is no proper getter setter method.

Comment: @AseemSalim Getter and setter of what?

Answer (score 1):

First thing when  you  are binding your viewmodel variable to to view then you should have getter and setter method for that variable just like this.

```
fun getUsername():String
{
    return username?.value!!//this is because username variable is MutableLiveData
}
fun setUsername(username:String?)
{
    this.username.value=username //this is bcoz username variable is MutableLiveData
}
```

When you are use `MutableLiveData` then you cannot set data like this

`android:text="@={viewmodel.username}"` 
 Because  `android:text` will return the string and you cannot set `string` to  `MutableLiveData` .You have do like this `MutableLiveData.value=string`.

And last whenever you are declaring `livedata` you should declare like this

`var username = MutableLiveData<String>()`

You're getting error because of this and your `edittext` value are not able to assign to your `variable` in `viewmodel` .